# Is GitHub shadowbanning my account by returning 404 to other users who access my profile?

Tags: github, user-accounts

I've recently created another account on GitHub to host stuff that I didn't want to associate with my main account. I used an email address under my domain name and verified it.

I was able to create repositories, push code, set up an SSH key, edit my profile and so on.

When I try to visit the account profile, or any of the repositories, while not logged in as that user, GitHub behaves as if the account doesn't exist, and returns a 404 error.

I tried again a month later and the behavior was the same.

I've seen other people complaining about the same issue, for example, in [this Reddit thread](https://old.reddit.com/r/github/comments/14htv2n/github_profile_returns_404/).

### Clarifications

- My profile is not set to private.
- My repositories are set to public.
- This is not a "machine account". It is a normal user account with no relationship to my main account. It was created manually as a normal account from a separate computer, with a different email address.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This happens when you account is marked as "spammy", usually automatically based on your email address or IP address. You can verify your account has been marked as spammy by going to https://github.com/settings/admin and seeing if you have the option to change your username. Spammy accounts will see "Please contact us if you’d like to rename your @username account" and a greyed out button.

The only way to get an account unmarked is to contact support.

Comment: Posts should not contain meta-commentary. First, you need to earn 50 rep (you are close) to criticize other answers. In this case, you might join the chat of one other answer as you have earned 20.

Comment: Related doc: [GitHub Community Guidelines](https://docs.github.com/en/site-policy/github-terms/github-community-guidelines)

Answer (score 8):

Check if you have your GitHub profile [set to private](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/customizing-your-profile/setting-your-profile-to-private).

GitHub will give 404 response for private repositories your currently logged in account does not have access to. This is so that unauthorized persons cannot even know whether they exist.

It appears that even private profiles should show basic information, so there must be something more going on with the profile that doesn't show up. It may be that GitHub is hiding "suspicious" profiles based on some criteria.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148979/discussion-on-answer-by-jpa-why-does-github-return-a-404-error-when-accessing-my); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: You should contact GitHub support.

---

While it's perfectly fine to use "private profile", "private account", "shadowbaning" and "spammy", these terms might mislead and cause false expectations and sterile discussions when used out of context and in places where extended discussions are not allowed, or cause that the conversation be derailed.

The GitHub personal account privacy setting only hides part of the user profile data. When the privacy setting is enabled the user profile page is still visible, showing a few user details.

As was mentioned in a [previous answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/172303/88163), GitHub pages could be hidden by GitHub automatic or manual process, making the hidden pages return error 404.

The cause that makes a user profile hidden is a violation of the [GitHub community guidelines](https://docs.github.com/en/site-policy/github-terms/github-community-guidelines). This cause also makes that other pages related to the "offending" account be hidden too. These guidelines include a reinstatement and appeal process.